# Django admin site -- list ForeignKey items as change-list on change page

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, changelist

In (a toy version of) my project, there are Owners who own any number of Objects. My `models.py` file looks like

```
class Owner(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()

class Object(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner)
```

My question relates to the change page for an Owner on the admin site, e.g.

```
http://mysite.com/admin/myapp/owner/1/.
```

Now I know that if I register `Object` as a `TabularInline` or a `StackedInline`, then I get an editable list of the Objects this Owner owns. However, in the real version of my project, an `Object` has something like 25 fields, not 2, and so neither of those options is really desirable aesthetically.

What I would really like instead is to essentially have a change-list of all the Objects an Owner owns appear on the Owner's change-page. (That way I get a nice compact listing of all the Owner's Objects, and if I need to edit the details of one, I can click on its link and edit it in its own page.) Basically I want the contents of

```
http://mysite.com/admin/myapp/object/?owner__id__exact=1
```

to appear within

```
http://mysite.com/admin/myapp/owner/1/.
```

Is there a way to do this?

PS: I'm using Django 1.4 and Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0):

You can define what form class and/or fields to use in each InlineModelAdmin using [these attributes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-options), and limit the amount of input fields per object that way.